# Erase hard drive before re-installing Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: system-installation, grubrescue

I had a desktop with Ubuntu 12.04 as the sole operating system -- no dual boot at all.

I want to re-install Ubuntu because of some complications. I know there are many methods out there, but none could work so I want to start all over by formatting the hard drive -- like it's fresh out of the box.

After formatting the drive, why does GRUB (error message) still appear when I boot the PC? Is it part of the motherboard? Or do I need to do a full format to erase Ubuntu from the hard drive completely?

How can I start from scratch? I am not attempting to FULL FORMAT the hard drive in my Windows laptop. Is this correct? Is NTFS file system the correct one to use?

Comment: NTFS is not correct although it is not impossible to do. Ubuntu typically uses ext4.

Answer (score 0):

Grub is still present on your HDD in [MBR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record). It is the part of disc where system looks on startup to determnine what to start. It shold be rewtitten when you reinstall your system.

Comment: How do you do that?

Comment: If you have Ubuntu 12.04 on a CD, DVD, or flashdrive, just boot into that, and you'll be given the choice of installing Ubuntu or booting from the LiveCD (or whatever).  Choose to install it, answer the prompts that come up, and when it installs, it will overwrite the old GRUB that's still there.  You'll end up with a clean install, fresh out of the box.

Comment: I have reformatted my hard drive, rebuilt by MBR using EaseUS. When I launch the desktop, its still says error unknown filesystem grub error.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to want to re-install Ubuntu (don't worry about clearing your MBR). Use the CD, DVD, or USB stick you used to originally install. Doing that should just do it, nothing else should be necessary.